# jQuery's CSS with functions and properties

Tags: jquery, css, properties

Say I have a something like this:

```
$('#someID').css({
    left: function(index,value) { return newv(value, 37, 39); },
    top: function(index,value) { return newv(value, 38, 40); }
});
```

and I want to include a `transform:rotate(30deg)` property. How would I go about doing that? After a bit of searching I haven't found anything.

To add several properties without functions:

```
$('#someID').css({
   "transform": "rotate(30deg)",
   "top": "-60px",
   "left": "600px"        
});
```

To add a single property:

```
$('#someID').css("transform", "rotate(30deg)");
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: ALmost there try `$('#someID').css("transform", "rotate(30deg)")`

Comment: fixed that, thank you - but that was not my question

Comment: what exactly is the question?

Comment: @Evan When i hit e.g. the left arrow key - my object moves left. I also want it to be rotated slightly to the left. So i need to somehow include the rotate property.

Comment: so doing $('#someID').css("transform", "rotate(30deg)"); doesnt work?

Comment: @Evan he wants it added to his code. Just add `transform: "rotate(30deg)"`

Comment: @Evan yes - it does. But if I do that the object will always be turned x-degrees, and I only want it to rotate of the key is pressed down. But I realize my question was very badly phrased, so I'll delete this one and repost it later if I dont figure it out

Comment: You're trying to incrementally increase the rotation on each tap of the arrow key?

Comment: @DavidThomas yes or something like add 2deg every second the key is pressed down

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're asking for but:

```
$('#someID').css({
    left: function(index,value) { return newv(value, 37, 39); },
    top: function(index,value) { return newv(value, 38, 40); },
    transform: 'rotate(30deg)'
});
```

works fine

You can also use a function here:

```
$('#someID').css({
    left: function(index,value) { return newv(value, 37, 39); },
    top: function(index,value) { return newv(value, 38, 40); },
    transform: function(index,value) { return "rotate(" + Math.random() * 90 + "deg)" }
});
```

but it's tricky to get the previous value because it isn't even a string anymore, but a transform matrix. So the best way is just to keep the previous value elsewhere and use that. For example:

```
$('#someID').css({
    left: function(index,value) { return newv(value, 37, 39); },
    top: function(index,value) { return newv(value, 38, 40); },
    transform: function(index,value) {
        value = this.rotate || 0;
        return "rotate(" + (this.rotate = newv(value, 39, 41)) + "deg)" }
});
```

Comment: That last peace of code didn't exactly do the trick but it helped me on the right track - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can try:

```
$('#someID').css({
    left: function(index,value) { return newv(value, 37, 39); },
    top: function(index,value) { return newv(value, 38, 40); },
    "transform": "rotate(30deg)"
});
```